# Angular Promise gives array of objects intead of array after being resolved in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I have the following code in my http Service(UserService):

```
module1.factory('UserService', ['$http', '$q', function($http, $q) {



      return {

        getModelValueTableValues1: function(CarLine, GeographyType, GeographyName, Duration, ModelId, ScenarioId, TimeKey) {



          return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/scenarioplan/models/data?ScenarioId=5&CarLine=Nissan%20-%20Rogue&TimeKey=Jul-16&Duration=1&Geographytype=National&GeographyName=National&ModelId=1001')
            .then(
              function successCallback(response) {



                return response.data;


              },
              function errorCallback(errResponse) {
                console.error('Error while fetching Model Parameter Table');
                return $q.reject(errResponse);
              }
            );
        },
```

ANd I have the following code in my controller:

```
$scope.getModelValueTableValues = function(CarLine, Geography, Duration, ModelId, ScenarioId) {

  UserService.getModelValueTableValues1(CarLine, Geography.split('-')[0], Geography.split('-')[1], Duration, ModelId, ScenarioId, '16-Jul')
    .then(
      function(d) {

        console.log("the data object from promise is", d);
        console.log("the data object from promise is", d.length);

        console.log('The Promise has been successfully resolved!!!!');
      },
      function(errResponse) {
        console.error('The Promise was not successfull');
      }
    );
};
```

But instead of returning an array of data, the promise, after getting resolved gives an array of objects as shown by the image below in my debug window(F12).
[image]

The reponse from Web Service Call seems to valid Data as shown by F12 Console Output below:

[image]

Can someone please help me to resolve this issue??
I have been trying to solve this throughout the day but without any success!

Comment: What does your `response` has ? 
`http://localhost:8080/scenarioplan/models/data?ScenarioId=5&CarLine=Nissan%20-%20Rogue&TimeKey=Jul-16&Duration=1&Geographytype=National&GeographyName=National&ModelId=1001`what does this url return

Comment: Hi @SusheelSingh, I have attached the image to question.

Comment: `array of data` can you explain this a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

$http implement promise already. Your function should

```
return $http.get('http://localhost:8080/scenarioplan/models/data?ScenarioId=5&CarLine=Nissan%20-%20Rogue&TimeKey=Jul-16&Duration=1&Geographytype=National&GeographyName=National&ModelId=1001');
```

Or if you want process data inside function you should.

```
return {

  getModelValueTableValues1:function(CarLine,GeographyType,GeographyName,Duration,ModelId, ScenarioId,TimeKey){         
     var deffered = $q.defer();
     $http.get('http://localhost:8080/scenarioplan/models/data?ScenarioId=5&CarLine=Nissan%20-%20Rogue&TimeKey=Jul-16&Duration=1&Geographytype=National&GeographyName=National&ModelId=1001')
       .then(
                    function successCallback(response){
                                   deffered.resolve(response);
                                }, 
                    function errorCallback(errResponse){
                          console.error('Error while fetching Model Parameter Table');
                           deffered(errResponse);
                           }
                        );
         return deffered.promise;
        },
```

Comment: @vanmohit...Your approach has partially shown me a road ahead. I am going to update you after trying this. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @Vanmohit.....I was able to finally get it to work. I had to use the function JSON.parse(angular.toJson(d.data)) inside my controller to process the data returned from your function.

Comment: You can return `$http`'s promise even when you want to process data inside `.then`, just return the result inside the function will do. For reject side use `return $q.reject(reason)`.

Comment: Actually, refer to OP's code, it is the correct way to do so. I mean the one in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete Steps that I followed to get my issue resolved.

1. As suggested by @vanmohit:
   I used his code inside my appfactory Service like this :

   ```
   return {
        getModelValueTableValues1: function(CarLine,GeographyType,GeographyName,Duration,ModelId, ScenarioId,TimeKey){         
            var deffered = $q.defer();
            $http.get('my url here')
                .then(
                       function successCallback(response){
                           deffered.resolve(response);
                       }, 
                       function errorCallback(errResponse){
                           console.error('Error while fetching Model Parameter Table');
                           deffered(errResponse);
                       }
               );
           return deffered.promise;
       },
   ```
2. In my controller code , I used this function :

   ```
   function(CarLine, Geography,Duration,ModelId, ScenarioId ){
       UserService.getModelValueTableValues1(CarLine,Geography.split('-')[0],Geography.split('-')[1],Duration,ModelId,ScenarioId,'16-Jul')
           .then(
               function(d) {
                  console.log("the data object from promise is",JSON.parse(angular.toJson(d.data))[1].paramName);
                  //console.log("the data object from promise is",d.length);
                  //JSON.parse(angular.toJson(resp))
                  $scope.firstrow = JSON.parse(angular.toJson(d.data));
                  console.log('The Promise has been successfully resolved!!!!');
              },
              function(errResponse){
                  console.error('The Promise was not resolved');
              }
          );
     };
   ```

And now I am able to parse through the JSON Data inside my controller!!
Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You can use $scope.firstrow = d.data that enough. By default $http will parse data to JSON.

Comment: @vanhonit....Also , I am unable to use the value returned from the promise and save it to a variable...Since it is an asynchronous call, I am unable to save it to a scope variable. Can you help me to do it?

Comment: @vanmohit I am unable to access  $scope.firstrow variable outside this function after I write  $scope.firstrow = d.data . WHen I access  $scope.firstrow  variable outside the function. It returns as undefined. Why so?

Comment: Ok....I figured out why...Because it is an asynchronous ajax call. Angular doesnt know when the promise will be returned.

Comment: You should read about isolate scope. In your case you can define variable outside callback function or check variable value before use.